# How to open custom (embedded) Google maps in full view?

Tags: google-maps

I want to open an embedded map that has custom routes in it in full view but clicking the "Google" logo only takes me to the map without all the custom information.

How do I open a custom map in full view?
I've tried googling the problem, but all techniques are obsolete since 2014 because we can no longer search for KML/KMZ files in the GMap search bar.

Can I find some kind of an "ID" or whatever in the source code using 'inspect' which I can then paste at the end of a GMaps URL to open that specific map?

*The specific map in question: [[link]](http://www.kektura.hu/utvonal/14-okt-reszturak/386-01-sz-tura-koszegi-hegyseg-kemeneshat-irottko-sarvar)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this will](http://www.kektura.hu/utvonal/14-okt-reszturak/386-01-sz-tura-koszegi-hegyseg-kemeneshat-irottko-sarvar?tmpl=component&print=1&layout=default&page=) be as close as you're likely to get.

Once you have this page, you can change some of the map embed options using inspect element (I changed the height to 800px in the screenshot below) or [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) or similar extension if you want something permanent.

[image: map w height changed to 800 px]

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Tom! I really only needed to take screenshots of the map, not share a link, so this is perfect.